# How can I reliably "transfer" shares to another person by using market transactions?

Tags: stocks, options, shares

Suppose I wish to transfer 100 shares of a $2,000 stock to person X (a trusted person). I have been holding this stock on behalf of person X for a few years now. Further suppose that it is infeasible to transfer the shares directly to X (e.g. due to very high fees). I thought about selling the 100 shares in my account, while buying 100 shares using X's account. I would also be sending the cash proceeds from selling the 100 shares ($200,000) to X. In this way, I would have effected a transfer of 100 shares from my account into X's account. However, there are some problems I see with this approach:

- Between the time that I sold 100 shares and the time that X buys the 100 shares, the share price may have increased.
- To minimize the risk of an increased share price, I will need to minimize the time between the selling and the buying. This means that X must have at least $200,000 in their account at the moment that I sell. Unfortunately, X likely does not have $200,000.

So my question is: how should I solve the problem?

I thought of a potential solution, but I'm not sure how realistic it is:

1. I buy a 3 month in-the-money call option with a strike price equal to the current price (or something close to it), and I simultaneously sell the 100 shares.
2. I transfer the cash proceeds of the sale to person X. I also transfer $20,000 extra to X as a precaution against an increase in stock price.
3. Once X receives the cash transfer (any time from a few hours to a few days), X uses the money I transferred to buy 100 shares, while I simultaneously sell my call option.
4. X then refunds the unused portion of the transferred funds back to me.

Is there anything conceptually incorrect with my solution to this problem?

(I understand that the transactions above could be in a legal grey area in some jurisdictions. However, I am primarily interested in knowing whether or not the scheme I thought of is a feasible solution to the problem I described)

Comment: what is the tax impact of these moves?

Comment: You are willing to give them cash - simply do that and let them purchase shares if they want. This question does not make sense, and appears to be trying to solve an unspoken problem.

Answer (score 2):

Transfer fees are very high but you're willing to transfer and $20,000 extra to X as a precaution against an increase in stock price?  That makes no sense.  Transfer fees aren't that high.

Your call idea works but there's a lot of slippage (B/A spread and time premium cost).  You could reduce the time premium component by buying high delta calls for which you need the cash in X's account, but the B/A slippage will likely increase.

If X has the appropriate option approval, do some no cost synthetic long stock poitions.  The margin requirement would be about 20% of the cost of the stock.  Lots of slippage but far, far less than the $20k you are talking about.

Best idea?  This is an era of no commission brokers  so fund X's account with at least enough cash to buy one share.  More if possible.  Then simultaneously transact multiple times in both accounts.  For example, put $20k in X's account.  Buy 10 shares while selling 10 shares in your account.  Upon settlement, transfer your cash in X's account.  Wash, rinse repeat.  No slippage other than the B/A spread.

Comment: Note that in some countries, transfer fees and brokerage fees are very high. The question is not specific to the US.

Comment: then you should specify the country so that answers can be question specific